# AngularJS - propogate updates to child context to parent context

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS application, which has a shell page. Shell page has a dropdown that contain a list of locations. In one of the internal pages, I have the functionality to add new locations. When a new location is added, it should immediately be displayed in the location dropdown of the shell page? How do I achieve this?

I know I should try with angular watchers. In fact, the same functionality is already there in the system. There's another client selection dropdown, when the client is changed, I broadcast an event, so the location dropdown gets re-populated. I'm not sure how to do the same when a new location is added.

Comment: Are you locations saved to the server or to js objects only? Could you share some code? It is hard to help without any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply broadcast an event to the parent context when a location gets added

```
$scope.addLocation = function () {
  // Add location code here
  $rootScope.$broadcast('location.added', data);
};
```

And then on the parent controller:

```
$scope.$on('location.added', function (event, data) {
  // Add new location to dropdown
};
```